# In R how to create big matrix in parallel

Tags: r, matrix, parallel-processing

Now I have a big matrix to build. It is very time-consuming. So I want to do it in parallel. For example, the matrix is 10^7 x 16, for each column I define a vector function to calculate the values. Like here, I should have 16 functions. Then, I want to assign the jobs to 16 cores to compute each column in parallel and finally give me this big matrix. How can I do that in R? Thanks!

Now I tried serval packages like parallel, foreach, doParallel. It doesn't work for some errors.

Here is a simple example I tried

```
library(parallel)


N1 = 100


rka = rep(1, N1)
rkb = rep(2, N1)
rkab = rep(3,N1)
rna = rep(4,N1)
rnb = rep(5,N1)
rnab = rep(6,N1)

E1 = cbind(rna,rnb-1,rnab,rka-1,rkb,rkab+1) 
E2 = cbind(rna,rnb,rnab,rka-1,rkb,rkab+1)   
E3 = cbind(rna-1,rnb,rnab,rka,rkb-1,rkab+1) 
E4 = cbind(rna,rnb,rnab,rka,rkb-1,rkab+1) 

VDelta = Matrix(0,nrow= 100,ncol= 4,sparse=TRUE)


 N_a<- cbind(E1[,1]+E1[,3]+E1[,4]+E1[,6],E2[,1]+E2[,3]+E2[,4]+E2[,6],E3[,1]+E3[,3]+E3[,4]+E3[,6],E4[,1]+E4[,3]+E4[,4]+E4[,6])
N_b<- cbind(E1[,2]+E1[,3]+E1[,5]+E1[,6],E2[,2]+E2[,3]+E2[,5]+E2[,6],E3[,2]+E3[,3]+E3[,5]+E3[,6],E4[,2]+E4[,3]+E4[,5]+E4[,6])

Mab <- M_0*(1-N_b/K_b)
Mba <- M_0*(1-N_a/K_a)


lambda_ab<- 2/(Mab+Mba)
C_b = 0.4
C_a = 0.4

fun = function(i){
  if(i == 2) VDelta[,2] <- C_b*(E2[,6] +1)
  else if (i == 4) VDelta[,4] <- C_a*(E4[,6] +1)
  else if (i == 1) VDelta[,1] <- lambda_ab[,1]*E1[,6]
  else VDelta[,3] <- lambda_ab[,3]*E3[,6]

  VDelta[,i] = VDelta[,i]
}  

no_cores = detectCores()
cl<-makeCluster(no_cores)
clusterExport(cl, "fun")
clusterExport(cl, "lambda_na")
clusterExport(cl, "lambda_nb")
clusterExport(cl, "Mab")
clusterExport(cl, "Mba")
clusterExport(cl, "lambda_ab")
clusterExport(cl, "E1")
clusterExport(cl, "E2")
clusterExport(cl, "E3")
clusterExport(cl, "E4")
clusterExport(cl, "C_b")
clusterExport(cl, "C_a")
clusterExport(cl, "VDelta")
V = parSapply(cl = cl, 1:4,fun)
stopCluster(cl)
```

Then, I got this error :

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  4 nodes produced errors; first error: object of type 'S4' is not subsettable
```

Comment: Note that in `fun` you specify `lambda_ab[,1]` and `lambda_ab[,3]` while you provide `lambda_ab = 0.2`.Changing those to `lambda_ab` indeed gives the error that you provide.

Comment: Sorry, it is a mistake when I copied the example. I edited it. Now the code still gives the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you export matrices created by the `Matrix` package to the cluster workers, you must load `Matrix` on the workers using something like:

```
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(Matrix))
```

I also suggest that you combine the exports for efficiency and readability:

```
clusterExport(cl, c("fun", "lambda_na", "lambda_nb", "Mab"))
```